# Built-in User management system in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I understand that there is built-in user management system tables or third party like Identity Manager to manager user's login username, password and user roles in MVC.

My question is should I create another table to store my system user profile with the foreign key? I mean besides username, password and user roles, I need to also store other things like NRIC, telephone number, email and etc.

or should I UPDATE the built-in user management system tables or third party like Identity Manager?

Hopefully someone understands what I am trying to describe here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways are possible and it all depends only on your preferences. The default user management in MVC is extensible and you can add more columns/properties to the the existing tables and model classes or crate new ones.

Here is an article that might help you: http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles

Comment: Thanks. I am now trying to do it with web form version first. I got it worked. Next I will try it with MVC approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Don't forget to vote if you found this question helpful.

Comment: i can't able to vote at the moment. need at least 15 reputation.